# Using Java find files added to S3 bucket folder in the last 1 hour

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We have 1,000,000 files in an S3 folder. Every hour some new files are added to the above folder.

Using Java how do i find the files added in the last 5 mins or last 1 hour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward way to do this is to scan the bucket and look for new timestamps. This is expensive, slow, and really a bad idea.

```
ObjectListing  objList = s3.listObjects(bucketname)
for (S3ObjectSummary obj in objList.getObjectSummaries()) {
  // compare obj.getLastModified(), a Date object
}
```

Second, you could structure your uploads to be lexicographically consistent to the date, then scan for a partial key. In the following case I'm scanning for entries in a given hour:

```
s3.listObjects(bucketname, "2015-02-01-15")
```

Finally, the best option is to use the relatively new [S3 Event Notifications](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html) to add each key to a SQS queue. I'm not going to detail this, even in pseudocode, but [Eric Hammond has a good entry detailing how to do this](http://alestic.com/2014/12/s3-bucket-notification-to-sqssns-on-object-creation).

Comment: Thanks @tedder42. This is very helpful.

So in your reply, you stated this: s3.listObjects(bucketname, "2015-02-01-15")

What are you implying?
---Should i add append YYYYDDMMHH to the uploaded file name
---Should i upload the files in folders with this format (YYYYDDMMHH)

Comment: yeah, I was implying you make the key something like this: `YYYYDDMMhhmm-filename.jpg`. But it's *really* not the best idea for several reasons (performance, s3 optimization/sharding). Event notifications SQS is much much better for this.